# NodeJS Local variable in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I, 
I know, there is a lot information about this on SO, but I didn't find the right answer for my situation.

I have this piece of code:

```
for(var i=0; i < shop.collections.length; i++){
  if(!shop.collection[i].active){
    var data = {
      name: shop.collection[i].name,
      visible: true
    };

    myOwnService.createCollection(data, accessToken, function(err, response, body){
      shop.collections[i].serviceId = body.id;
  })
}
```

My problem is that `shop` is undefined in the `myOwnService.createCollection()` service. What is the right way to access the `shop` variable in the callback, so how I can update the object so I can save the result?

Comment: You can use let instead of var if you are using es6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shop` is in the parent scope of the `myOwnService.createCollection` function hence it is accessible inside it.

Only issue in above code is `i` used in `callback` which will always be the last value as it will be executed after event loop.

Use `IIFE` wrapper around `myOwnService.createCollection` so that scope of `i` could be passed.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < shop.collections.length; i++) {
  if (!shop.collection[i].active) {
    var data = {
      name: shop.collection[i].name,
      visible: true
    };
    (function(i) {
      myOwnService.createCollection(data, accessToken, function(err, response, body) {
        shop.collections[i].serviceId = body.id;
      });
    })(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be accessible inside where you try to access. If you are tying Chrome debugger to see if it has the value, Chrome debugger sometime mess up and shows it like is not available.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3491